# how to get product thumbnail and product url in order confirmation email

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, product-images, simple-product, order-confirmation

I have tried already mentioned solution for getting product thumbnail image along with product url (link to product)using below solution

**/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml**

```
<?php echo $_item->getThumbnail(); ?>

<?php echo $this->$_item->getThumbnail()); ?>

<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_item->getThumbnail()); ?>
```

and on **/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.html**

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<!--Custom-->
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<!--Custom-->
<?php $_giftMessage; ?>
<div class="table-wrapper order-items">
    <table class="data table table-order-items" id="my-orders-table" summary="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items Ordered') ?>">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items Ordered') ?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col name"><?php echo $this->__('Image')?></th> //<-This code
                <th class="col name"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product Name') ?></th>
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                <th class="col sku"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SKU') ?></th>
                <!--Product Image 17-02-17 -->
                <th class="col price"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Price') ?></th>
                <th class="col qty"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></th>
                <th class="col subtotal"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subtotal') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 0; ?>
        <?php $_count = $_items->count(); ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = ''?>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
    continue;
} ?>
```

but not getting either of product url and product image on order confirmation mail when i tries testing from my end.any solutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to load product to get thumbnail and url .

```
    <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
 echo $product->getThumbnail();
echo  $product->getProductUrl(); ?>
```

//get image url

```
$imagewidth=200;
$imageheight=200;
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
 echo $image_url
```

Comment: i have tried above steps. i have put the code in /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/succ‌​ess.html added $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loa‌​d($item->getProductI‌​d()); <?php echo $product->getThumbnail(); echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?> in both default.phtml and items.phtml but iam not getting any results. this is a screenshot of my confirmation email. prntscr.com/e9vsx7 wherer am i going wrong?plz explain where i have to put these codes?

Comment: try this code `$_item->getProduct()->getThumbnail();`

Comment: shall i echo it like echo $_item->getProduct()->getThumbnail() in both default.html and items.html file

Comment: I have tried code and implemented but no result still getting no image and proper product url link can you plz explain in brief where to put these code coz i have put in both default.phtml and items.phtml file and tried but no luck

Comment: i have tried   <div class="product-name"><a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>&nbsp;<img src="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getThumbnail();?>"></div>
but no image is showing

Comment: @YogeshRaghav i tested this code it is working can you tell me which file you are editing? you must edit `templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` if you are editing email template

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order
default.phtml its working for product url but not for showing size..can u tell me sir how to display image its like <img src="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getThumbnail(); ? ">?

Comment: @YogeshRaghav i added the image url code too

Comment: @YogeshRaghav kindly mark as accepted  solution so it can help other fellow community member. and i don't see any upvote

Comment: i have marked solution as accepted and while giving upvoting iam getting this http://prntscr.com/ecb2p4 also sir we dont have to use echo instead have to call the variable as <?= $image_url ?> thanks alot

Comment: @YogeshRaghav you required **25 point** to give upvote any question

Comment: no sir i will manage to get extra points..lets hope i'll manage to achieve this

Comment: @QaisarSatti: module-catalog/Helper/Product.php - can not we use the method `getThumbnailUrl` to display the image ? Tried using `$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
$product->getThumbnailUrl()` to display product thumbnail image, but its not working. `getThumbnail` does not give full image path to display

Comment: @Vikram follow https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-product-images/

Comment: @QaisarSatti, I saw the blog post, and I have already loaded the product collection in my controller. I need to know is it possible to fetch product thumbnail image using this method `$product->getThumbnailUrl()` without writing `imageHelper` ?

Comment: @Vikram there is not method like `$product->getThumbnailUrl()` as far i know.

Comment: `module-catalog/Helper/Product.php` line #258 `public function getThumbnailUrl($product)`

Comment: @Vikram `$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product');
echo $imageHelper->getThumbnailUrl($product);` will do that

Comment: @QaisarSatti - I tried but not sure what I am doing wrong. I have posted my question with code here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211640/magento-2-fetch-product-thumbnail-image

Comment: Thank you @QaisarSatti , your code helps me to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this code myself, its working.

override **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml** and use this code in it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
?>
<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU'); ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php
            $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
        <table class="message-gift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message') ?></h3>
                    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:'); ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and in override **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/it‌​ems.phtml** and use:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Image'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price'); ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php
                if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:'); ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: so can i use same code in default.phtml and items.phtml both for simple product and configurable product or i have to change some coding in both file?can u please brief this.?

Comment: I had answered according to magento2. Now I've updated the answer. You can use this code in default.phtml and items.phtml but don't forget that first two lines are for loading the order, so that could vary.

Comment: i have tried above steps. i have put the code in  /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.html added 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
<?php echo $product->getThumbnail();
echo  $_product->getProductUrl(); ?> 
in both default.phtml and items.phtml but iam not getting any results.
this is a screenshot of my confirmation email.
http://prntscr.com/e9vsx7
wherer am i going wrong?plz explain where i have to put these codes?

Comment: I have tried code suggested by you and qaiser sir but no result :(

Comment: any reply please?

Comment: which magento verison are you using?

Comment: iam using magento 2.1.3

Comment: then why are you using **Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')**

Comment: it belongs to magento1

Comment: I've updated my answer,  use that

Comment: ok  great sir.do i have to use that query in success.phtml and what queries i need ro use in both default.phtml and items.phtml?

Comment: if you want to get details on order success page, then you must use in success.phtml. If you want to somewhere else, then use the code in that phtml.

Comment: no my success.phtml is fine but the issue is with order confirmation mail. the product thumbnail image and product link is not appearing in that.so didi have to use the code gave by you in default.phtml and items.phtml? because i dont want anything to display on success.phtml aprt from what is already there.

Comment: can you place an order with my email id: manishjoy1993@hotmail.com? then I'll be able to see the error

Comment: sure sir hold on but i have to register you first sir..orelse you can from your end..this is testing website : http://111.118.214.83/ . you can register,place order and see that you only get details like product info along with its shipping details. you wont see product image thumbnail along with the link to product.
i am also forwarding the mail i have got to your email so you can check form your end.

Comment: i have forwared mail to you sir from email id:yogeshraghav3043@gmail.com  ..kindly check in spam folder too

Comment: have updated the answer, use that in items.phtml

Comment: after having success, please delete my customer account from admin panel

Comment: make changes by overidding **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml**

Comment: ok sir i will delete your account from admin panel

Comment: n if you found my answer helpful, please upvote.. thanks in advance

Comment: sir i have implied that in items.phtml but when i check my email its showing as blank with no item to show. is it misbehaving after including tat bunch of code ??
 <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>"></img>
      </th>
see this: http://prntscr.com/ebhzz0
what is going wrong here?

Comment: its showing blank for the fields after implementing that code?
see here: http://prntscr.com/ebhzz0 
so where to use that code coz if i use directky in items.phtml the rest of fiekd is hiding and not showing up

Comment: bro, you need to debug... try to print the desired data and see if it comes in mail, you must have made some mistake, thats why that is not working

Comment: i havent made mistake sir i have used the code u gave in items.phtml and tried to print image as <img src="<?php echo $image_url" ?>"></img> in items.phtml after including the code gave by you at top but the main data is showing blank....can u tell me how to test where its going wrong coz i cant check or debug error directly in mail..there has to some point where i can check what mail is suppose to go ..iam reallly confused and this issue need to be rectified sir

Comment: I've added one answer, its working for me.try that and plz upvote if helpful.

Comment: where is it i cant see the answer sir..while approving its saying i need 2K points in order to approve the answer something like that..can u please repeat answer and also state in which exact file i have to edit.

Comment: there might be some problem, by the way I've updated my previous answer, check that. it has worked for me

Comment: ok thank you sir for your support. i'll try it out.by the way i also want a product url link also where if user clicks that link he will go to product page what he/she bought..can it be possible. actually iam working on a new website and my sir asked to create a product url(link) in order confirmation mail

Comment: ok, for product url, simply use: $_product->getProductUrl();

Comment: can i directly use this link in items. phtml or default.html
in items.phtml do i have to write as shown below
<table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /*  __('Items'); ?>
                </th>
               <th>echo $_product </th> <--Likes this
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= /*   __('Qty'); ?>
                </th>
             
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

Comment: do i have to use $_product->getProductUrl() directly in items.phtml..like 
echo $_product near item???

Comment: no just add th in items.phtml and add td in default.phtml like you added image. under td tag use $_product->getProductUrl();

Comment: ok great so i have used <td>$product->getProductUrl()</td> in default.phtml and in items.phtml i have to use <th>  how to call product url here like (_Img)</th>....only this confusion i have

Comment: i have used <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Url'); ?>      
      </th>  in items.phtml to call product url is it fine?

Comment: it only adds table header, but to show url you need to add table data **<td>** in default.phtml

Comment: i used sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order default.phtml..

<td>
        <?php      $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
    </td> and in items.phtml->   <?=   __('Image'); ?>
                </th> still blank..
 http://prntscr.com/eby1h7

Comment: manish sir that code i snot working.i have tried in default.html the same snippet and used <th><?= __('Image')</th> in items.phtml in order to get the result but still showing blank...

Comment: sir luckily i managed to get product url in my order confirmation mail but still struggling for image. can you please check the solution u gave me have any syntax error coz when iam applying same snippet in default.html..my order confirmation showing blank <table> that means there is some syntax error in the code or something else coz iam trying to copy the same snippet you gave me but its not working any idea?