# Magento 2 - Fetch Product Thumbnail Image

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, 
                                    Collection $productCollection, Config $eavConfig, ProductFactory $productFactory, Product $productHelper,
                                    Status $productStatus, Visibility $productVisibility
    ) {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {


            $productModel = $this->productFactory->create();
            $module_products = array();

            $this->productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]
            );
            $this->productCollection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

            foreach ($this->productCollection as $product) {

                $productId = $product->getId();
                $product = $productModel->load($productId);
                $thumbnailImageUrl = $this->productHelper->getThumbnailUrl($product);

                $my_product[$productId]['name'] = $product->getName();
                $my_product[$productId]['thumbnail'] = $thumbnailImageUrl;
            }

            if(isset($currentId)){
                $module_products[$currentId] = $my_product[$currentId];
            } else{
                $module_products = $my_product;
            }



        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $template = 'Vendor_Module::result.phtml';


        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate($template)
                ->setData('module_products', $module_products)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Here method `getThumbnail` gives product name but not with complete path. Under `module-catalog/Helper/Product.php` - I have used the method `getThumbnailUrl` to display the image, but it
is thowing `500 Internal Server` exception

How do I get product thumbnail image with URL in order to display it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code working for me also optimize that too

```
public function execute() {


        $imagewidth=50;
        $imageheight=50;
        $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'));
        foreach ($this->productCollection as $product) {

             $productId = $product->getId();
             $productSku = $product->getSku();

            echo $thumbnailImageUrl = $this->productHelper->getThumbnailUrl($product);

        }

    }
```

output

```
http://localhost/magento22/pub/media/catalog/product//m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
http://localhost/magento22/pub/media/catalog/product//m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
http://localhost/magento22/pub/media/catalog/product//m/b/mb03-black-0.jpg
```

Code i tried

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

{

    public function __construct(Context $context,
                            PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                            JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
                            Collection $productCollection,
                            ProductFactory $productFactory,
                            Product $productHelper
    ) {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute() {


        $imagewidth=50;
        $imageheight=50;
        $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'));
        foreach ($this->productCollection as $product) {

             $productId = $product->getId();
             $productSku = $product->getSku();

            echo $thumbnailImageUrl = $this->productHelper->getThumbnailUrl($product).'<br />';

            $productThumbnail = $thumbnailImageUrl ;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I am still unable to get output and its throwing 500 exception. Can you once try with my code which may expose why I am getting error

Comment: @Vikram added the code which i tried i found no error make sure you set developer mode and remove generation and cache folder too

Comment: Well I am loading `$product = $productModel->load($productModel->getIdBySku($productSku));`. Could this be an issue ?

Comment: @Vikram no need of loading that use this code it fulfill your requirement

Comment: I figured out that when I include ` Product $productHelper` and  `$this->productHelper = $productHelper;` in `__construct` functions, it throws exception `500 Internal Server error`

Comment: @Vikram copy paste this code and check i didn't find any error or send me complete code i can look at that. after adding that make sure remove var/generation folder.

Comment: I have posted my question with actual code I am using. Also what is the preferred approach to fetch thumbnail image url. Using `Helper\Product` or the one you mentioned in your answer ?

Comment: @Vikram use the image builder as i mention on blog

Comment: But what could be the reason here. The code and method seems fine to me. I am just trying to explore why it is not working. Even if I try to use `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`, it still gives me internal server error

Answer (score 2):

Please use code like below.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
$imageUrl = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')
->constrainOnly(FALSE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize($width, $height)
->getUrl();
```

Comment: I discourage direct use of `objectManager `. Can you post your answer wrt to my code ?

Comment: then just add dependency of "Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image" in your Controller class then use like $this->imageHelper

Answer (score 0):

Please use code like below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {


protected imageHelper; 

public function __construct(Context $context, 
                            PageFactory $resultPageFactory, 
                            JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, 
                            Collection $productCollection, 
                            ProductFactory $productFactory,
                            ImageHelper $imageHelper
    ) {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute() {

        $productModel = $this->productFactory->create();
        $width = 100;
        $height = 100;


        foreach ($this->productCollection as $product) {

            $productId = $product->getId();
            $productSku = $product->getSku();
            $product = $productModel->load($productModel->getIdBySku($productSku));

            $imageUrl = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                            ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                            ->resize($width, $height)
                            ->getUrl();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have revised my question with ImageHelper. It gives 500 internal server error.

Comment: Check my code i have used like $imageUrl = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                            ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                            ->resize($width, $height)
                            ->getUrl();

Comment: Did you check my question with `getThumbnailUrl` method using `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product` instead of `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image` ?

Comment: getThumbnailUrl function return "" in Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product