# Get product image on success page | Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, order-success-page

I need to display product image in success page without using object manager which is bad practice.
thank you

Comment: You may take some help from this [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160477/how-to-get-product-thumbnail-and-product-url-in-order-confirmation-email)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Helper Image to achieve that:

in your PHTML

```
/** @var Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $_helperImage */

$_helperImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$items = GET THE ITEMS IN THE ORDER
$product = $item->getProduct();

$producImg = $_helperImage->init($product, 'small_image')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
```

That way, you can get the Image URL of the current product in your order.

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code for fetch product small image-based on product id.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Block;

use Exception;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;


class customImage extends Template
{

    /**
     * Small image value.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const SMALL_IMAGE = 'small_image';

    /**
     * @var ImageFactory
     */
    public $imageFactory;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    public $logger;    

    public function __construct(
            Template\Context $context,
            ImageFactory $imageFactory,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            LoggerInterface $logger,            
            array $data = array()
    ) {
        $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get Product Image url
     * @param productId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl($productId) // Pass product id here.
    {
        $imageUrl = null;
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            if ($product) {
                $imageHelper = $this->imageFactory->create()->init($product, self::SMALL_IMAGE);
                $imageUrl = $imageHelper->getUrl();
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }
        return $imageUrl;
    }
}
```